# How do I write characters out using Write() in C?

Tags: c, sockets, bmp

I'm trying to write a bitmap file to the browser in C.
I can write the printable ascii parts like this,

```
write (socket, "BM", 2);
```

but how do I write the non-printable ones with their decimal value?
I know that if I was writing to a file I could use something like this,

```
fprintf(fp, "%c%c%c%c" , 40,0,0,0);
```

But I don't know how to do the same thing but instead just write it to the socket...
Please help me out, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap a file descriptor in a `FILE` structure (thus enabling use of all the `printf` family) using `fdopen()`:

```
int fd = socket(...);
FILE *fp = fdopen(fd, "w+");
```

Now, `fp` is just like any other FILE*. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

If the bytes you want to write are static, you can simply define a buffer and use it...

```
char buffer[]={40,0,0,0};
write(socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

or inline...

```
write(socket, (char[]){40,0,0,0}, 4);
```

The best approach depends where the characters are coming from (are they dynamic / are they already in a buffer), how many there are, whether or not you want to do encoding, where the size element comes from.. etc etc..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sprintf` for that.

```
char data[4];
sprintf(data, "%c%c%c%c", 40, 0, 0, 0);
write(socket, data, 4);
```

**EDIT:**

If you'r using this a lot, you can write your own function for formated write to socket like this:

```
void writef(int socket, const char * format, ...) {
    char buffer[1024];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int length = vsprintf(buffer, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    write(socket, buffer, length);
}
```

and then you can simply call `writef(socket, "%c%c%c%c", 40, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: Thanks, is there any way without using another function? I mean an even simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

You could `snprintf` the values into a char buffer, and then `write` out the buffer.